# Usage of "Go At"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, usage, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the phrase "go at" [here](http://www.therichest.com/rich-list/rich-countries/lets-sea-the-10-biggest-navies-in-the-world/10/):

> With 10 aircraft carrier groups, dozens of destroyers, 22 cruisers (nearest rival Russia has five) and a large modern submarine force, the US Navy rules the seas. This blue-water branch of the US military is run by more than 320,000 people and is also the owner of the largest warships in the world. The Nimitz-class aircraft carriers weigh around 100,000 tons each and along with their escorts can operate as “mini-navies”, giving the USA a practically unlimited strategic ability to project power in any of the world’s oceans and seas. Just one of these aircraft carriers could ***go at*** No.16 of the list of largest navies by tonnage, just ahead of the Royal Australian Navy at 98,426 tons.

I cannot find a definition of "*go at*" that fits this usage.  What does it mean to "*go at*" a particular position on a list?  Is it slang?

Comment: hi. Just a hint: would you expect to find slang in an article that has this kind of writing?

Answer (score 2):

It's "go" using definition 8 from [here](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=go%20definition).  "To be regularly kept or put in a place."  In the list of the world's navies, ordered by tonnage, a single Nimitz class carrier occupies position 16.  It's a slightly odd usage with "at."  "Go in" is a more common pairing.